# My Firebase SigninWithEmailandPassword did not work

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

my code does not read any statement eventhough i have enter correct email and password.
the firebase connection already define and the email and password already in the database.

this is my code for activity_login

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_login"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nani.mrt.Login">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_navlogo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/login_input_email"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id = "@+id/login_email"
        android:hint="Enter your email"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_input_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/login_input_password"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id = "@+id/login_password"
        android:hint="Enter your password"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:inputType = "textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:text="SIGN IN"
    android:background="#263238"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="login"
    android:id="@+id/btnsignin"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnsignin"
    android:text="FORGOT PASSWORD?"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnforgot"
    android:onClick="forgotpassword" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnforgot"
    android:id="@+id/login_layout_or"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#c4c8c9" />
    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="OR"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#c4c8c9" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_layout_or"
    android:text="Register an account" android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="register"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:id="@+id/register"
   />
```

and this is my code for Login activity

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
private Button btnsignin;
private EditText editTextemail, editTextpassword;
private TextView register, btnforgot;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    btnsignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);
    btnforgot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnforgot);

    editTextemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    editTextpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);

    register = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);

    btnsignin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnforgot.setOnClickListener(this);
    register.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btnsignin) {
        // signinUser(editTextemail.getText().toString(),editTextpassword.getText().toString());

        String email = editTextemail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextpassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        //authenticate user
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // there was an error
                            if (password.length() < 6) {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                               // editTextpassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                            }                             
                        } else {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, HomeNavigation.class);
                            intent.putExtra("usernamekey", editTextemail.getText().toString());
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
    if (view == btnforgot) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, ForgotPassword.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (view == register) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, RegisterAs.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Comment: Log `task.getException()` inside `if (!task.isSuccessful())`

Comment: can you tell us what problem you're facing! are you getting any error or exception or anything?

Comment: What actually didn't work? Please, be precise.

Comment: Can you share log?